# URL to use for Paypal IPN Simulator

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I am using the simulator at https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications/ipn_simulator to check my IPN script located at www.domain.com/ipn.asp

as part of my own IPN script, i need to re-post the IPN message that i receive, back to Paypal.

1. if i post back to https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/websc -
   the IPN simulator gives me a failed message ("We're sorry, we could not send an IPN.").
2. But if i post back to https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr (the
   live script) - the IPN simulator gives me a success message ("IPN sent successfully") - BUT,
   my own IPN scripts tells me that the final response from paypal -
   was `INVALID`, even though i am posting everything back along with
   the `cmd=_notify-validate&`

So - what URL should i be using, and could there be any reason i keep getting this `INVALID` final response?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr is the correct address for testing with the sandbox. The address you listed in your question is missing the `r` at the end of `webscr`.

There are a lot of reasons you could be getting an INVALID response. You'll need to debug your code to find the issue. I used PHP for my IPN listener, so I can't be of much help with that.

Comment: you're the man - how could i have missed that `r`!!  thanks a mil!